# ReturnURL not working with authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a web application and trying to add authentication for all Forms.

Initially I tried this and is working at my default.aspx page after successfull login:

```
Session["username"] = username;
Response.Redirect("/Home.aspx");
```

After that I tried to add authentication in web.config, here is the configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="2880"  path="/" /> 
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**and in code (default.aspx)**

```
 string strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
 Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
```

**I see ReturnURI string is okay (/Home.aspx)**

But it is not redirecting to the Home.aspx page, Not sure what is wrong ! I suspect some path is wrong here!

Thanks

Comment: try with Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");

Comment: @Azad that's working but I want it to work with "ReturnUrl"